ServiceStack MicrosoftGraphAuthProvider authentication fails when Client Secret contains special characters
We've been using the ServiceStack MicrosoftGraphAuthProvider successfully for some time, however a recent update to the Client Secret caused the authentication to stop working for all users. The sign-in attempt fails, and the browser ends up at the URL /#f=Unknown relative to the site root. The Client Secret is in this format.
We noticed that the new Client Secret contained a plus character where the old one did not, which appears to be the cause of the problem. The HTTP POST request which attempts to acquire an access token is URL encoding the redirect_uri parameter, but does not appear to be encoding the client_secret parameter. We were able to work around the issue by manually URL encoding the new secret in our application configuration (replacing the '+' with '%2b'), at which point users could sign-in successfully.
Is there any way to configure the MicrosoftGraphAuthProvider so that it URL encodes the client_secret parameter?

Edit : I've found where the token is being requested in the source code and in doing so, have answered my original question - it can't be configured to URL encode the secret.
From the MicrosoftGraphAuthProvider source code :
    protected override async Task<string> GetAccessTokenJsonAsync
        (string code, AuthContext ctx, CancellationToken token = default)
    {
        var accessTokenParams =
            $"code={code}&client_id={ConsumerKey}&client_secret={ConsumerSecret}&redirect_uri={this.CallbackUrl.UrlEncode()}&grant_type=authorization_code";
        var contents = await AccessTokenUrlFilter(ctx, AccessTokenUrl)
            .SendStringToUrlAsync(method:HttpMethods.Post, requestBody:accessTokenParams, contentType: MimeTypes.FormUrlEncoded, token: token).ConfigAwait();
        return contents;
    }



In your case, the + symbol in the client_secret needs to be replaced with %2B to avoid issues.

Could you edit your question and add your current code in it to know how you are acquiring token?

We don't have any custom code to acquire the token, it's probably happening in the MicrosoftGraphAuthProvider class, or possibly the OAuth2Provider which it inherits from. I based my question on the requests I observed in Fiddler.

Try this var encodedSecret = Uri.EscapeDataString(appSettings.GetString("oauth.microsoftgraph.AppSecret")); authProvider.AppSecret = encodedSecret; for client secret encoding.

Actually, I think I've found where the token is being requested in the source code and in doing so, have answered my original question : it can't be configured to URL encode the secret. But the method in question is virtual so would be easy enough to override and fix: What you suggested should work as well - thanks for your input!

The problem you're experiencing is due to the client_secret not being URL-encoded when included in the token request. Special characters like + need to be properly encoded as %2B to ensure the request is processed correctly by Microsoft Graph.
To resolve this, you can manually encode the client_secret before passing it into the MicrosoftGraphAuthProvider. Here’s how you can do it:
var encodedSecret = Uri.EscapeDataString(appSettings.GetString("oauth.microsoftgraph.AppSecret"));
authProvider.AppSecret = encodedSecret;

This ensures that any special characters in the client_secret are properly encoded, and you won’t run into issues caused by characters like +.
In your case, you can make use of below modified code as you mentioned in question edit:
From the  MicrosoftGraphAuthProvider source code  :
protected override async Task<string> GetAccessTokenJsonAsync
    (string code, AuthContext ctx, CancellationToken token = default)
{
    var accessTokenParams = 
        $"code={code}&client_id={ConsumerKey}&client_secret={ConsumerSecret.UrlEncode()}&redirect_uri={this.CallbackUrl.UrlEncode()}&grant_type=authorization_code";

    var contents = await AccessTokenUrlFilter(ctx, AccessTokenUrl)
        .SendStringToUrlAsync(
            method: HttpMethods.Post,
            requestBody: accessTokenParams,
            contentType: MimeTypes.FormUrlEncoded,
            token: token
        ).ConfigAwait();

    return contents;
}

